# Is it possible to change an AD user account using Ruby LDAP?

Tags: ruby, active-directory, ldap

Using Ruby LDAP running on Linux, I can create a new Active Directory user account without a problem. Now I want to be rename a user account username.

When I try to change the `sAMAccountName`, it doesn't work. Is it possible to change an AD user account using Ruby LDAP? If so, how?

Comment: Max, have you had any luck with the modrdn command below?

Answer (score 4):

What is the error returned, when you say "doesn't work"?  You should be perfectly capable to alter the value of `sAMAccountName` using any LDAP client or library provided that the connection was originally authenticated as an administrative user (i.e. a user who has the permission to alter the said entry and entry attribute.)

---

**UPDATE**

It would appear from the error message that, although you claim to only attempt the modification of `sAMAccountName`, a change of `CN` was also attempted, or `CN` is special (it is part of the `DN`.)

In order to change the `CN` you'll probably have to use [`modrdn`](http://ruby-ldap.sourceforge.net/rdoc/classes/LDAP/Conn.html#M000029) to rename the `CN` part of the `DN` (the standardized equivalent of `MoveHere`):

```
conn.modrdn('CN=old-name,OU=orgunit,DC=domain', 'CN=new-name', true)
conn.modify('CN=new-name,OU=orgunit,DC=domain', 'sAMAccountName' => new-acct)
```

Answer (score 1):

I see this is a year old but I'll answer anyway.

I'm using [ActiveLdap](http://ruby-activeldap.rubyforge.org/doc/) in a Rails app....which uses the [Ruby/LDAP](http://github.com/alexey-chebotar/ruby-ldap) gem behind it.  I can do the following in my code.

```
aduser = User.find("matt")
puts aduser.cn
# prints 'matt'
puts aduser.distinguishedname
# prints 'cn=matt,ou=here,dc=my,dc=domain'

# THIS RENAMES THE ACCOUNT AND AUTOMATICALLY HANDLES ALL THE ATTRIBUTES
# THAT NEED TO CHANGE... e.g. name, cn, distinguishedname, dn
aduser.cn = "newmatt"
aduser.save
```

You should be able to look through the ActiveLdap code and figure out how they do that through Ruby/Ldap.

What doesn't currently work in ActiveLdap however is 'newsuperior', so there's not currently a way to move an object from one container to another.  I'm still working out how to make that happen.

Matt

Answer (score 0):

Any chance you can post some of your code?  Also you may want to try using the [MoveHere](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa705991(VS.85).aspx#) method which is really using for moving user accounts, but can also be used to rename an account.